# Docker proxy timeouts with docker buildx build

Tags: docker, buildx

I'm trying to build amd64 images on a M1 Mac. After a reboot, the build command below works for about day and starts giving errors like the one below.

The Dockerfile starts with

```
FROM python:3.10.10-slim as build
```

and running

```
docker buildx build 
  --build-arg http_proxy=http://myproxy:8080 
  --build-arg https_proxy=http://myproxy:8080 
  --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.edu:8080 
  --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy:8080 
  --load --platform linux/amd64 .
```

fails with

```
  1 | >>> FROM python:3.10.10-slim as build
  2 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: python:3.10.10-slim: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.10.10-slim": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp myproxy:8080: i/o timeout
```

Prior the running buildx build I've run:

```
docker buildx create --use --name mybuilder 
  --driver=docker-container 
  --driver-opt env.http_proxy=http://myproxy:8080 
  --driver-opt env.https_proxy=http://myproxy:8080 
  --driver-opt '"env.no_proxy='$no_proxy'"'
```

Comment: Also I experienced the same problem, it is unthinkably annoying and very likely a buildkit bug. Buildkit is the new docker builder crap.